# ubuntu upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 very slow boot

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have tried following things, and im beginner with ubuntu so afraid to make some changes in firmware or booting sequence might go something wrong  please help me.

```
$ systemd-analyze
   Startup finished in 3.752s (firmware) + 4.733s (loader) + 37.788s (kernel) + 1min 27.819s (userspace) = 2min 14.094s
    graphical.target reached after 1min 25.853s in userspace
```

systemd-analyze blame

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
```

```
   26.570s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
         23.755s systemd-journal-flush.service
         16.831s teamviewerd.service
         15.501s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         14.206s dev-loop33.device
         14.160s dev-loop34.device
         14.043s dev-loop30.device
         14.013s dev-loop31.device
         13.862s dev-loop27.device
         13.759s dev-loop26.device
         13.757s dev-loop29.device
         13.270s dev-loop28.device
         13.149s networkd-dispatcher.service
         12.880s dev-loop24.device
         12.876s dev-loop32.device
         12.753s dev-loop25.device
         12.504s dev-loop22.device
         12.455s snapd.service
         12.439s dev-loop21.device
         12.308s dev-loop23.device
         12.197s dev-loop20.device
         11.757s udisks2.service
         10.796s dev-loop18.device
         10.750s dev-loop19.device
         10.524s dev-loop16.device
         10.103s dev-loop17.device
         10.086s ModemManager.service
          9.614s dev-loop15.device
          9.418s dev-loop14.device
          9.196s dev-loop13.device
          8.938s dev-loop12.device
          8.744s accounts-daemon.service
          8.738s NetworkManager.service
          8.324s dev-loop7.device
          8.251s dev-loop11.device
          8.145s dev-loop9.device
          7.849s dev-loop10.device
          7.010s dev-loop8.device
          6.960s apport.service
          6.803s dev-loop5.device
          6.209s gpu-manager.service
          5.929s dev-loop6.device
          5.867s dev-loop2.device
          5.866s dev-loop4.device
          5.660s dev-loop3.device
          5.591s bolt.service
          5.515s apparmor.service
          5.339s speech-dispatcher.service
          5.322s networking.service
          5.262s bluetooth.service
          5.212s systemd-udevd.service
          5.125s avahi-daemon.service
          5.124s thermald.service
          5.054s rsyslog.service
          4.583s dev-loop1.device
          4.306s snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-81.mount
          4.248s wpa_supplicant.service
          4.246s dev-loop0.device
          3.938s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-86.mount
          3.880s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-352.mount
          3.762s snap-docker-372.mount
          3.724s systemd-logind.service
          3.665s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-288.mount
          3.599s snap-docker-381.mount
          3.518s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
          3.380s polkit.service

          2.873s snap-krita-44.mount
          2.812s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-59.mount
          2.660s upower.service
          2.625s snap-obs\x2dstudio-519.mount
          2.624s systemd-rfkill.service
          2.602s lvm2-pvscan@8:3.service
          2.585s snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-77.mount
          2.553s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
          2.505s snap-docker-384.mount
          2.447s snap-highlighterpdf-5.mount
          2.363s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-57.mount
          2.305s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount
          2.302s lvm2-monitor.service
          2.194s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          2.158s snap-microk8s-652.mount
          2.102s snap-krita-48.mount
          2.094s grub-common.service
          2.075s snap-core-6818.mount
          2.054s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-88.mount
          2.011s packagekit.service
          1.751s fwupd.service
          1.742s keyboard-setup.service
          1.731s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1122.mount
          1.705s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-284.mount
          1.680s snap-microk8s-608.mount
          1.514s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-87.mount
          1.479s snap-core-6673.mount
          1.464s binfmt-support.service

           1.342s systemd-sysctl.service
          1.225s lightdm.service
          1.222s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          1.162s colord.service
           955ms snap-core-6964.mount
           936ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           875ms boot.mount
           867ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           830ms snap-obs\x2dstudio-525.mount
           819ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           786ms snap-core18-970.mount
           735ms dev-mqueue.mount
           721ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           720ms dev-hugepages.mount
           718ms systemd-journald.service
           713ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-F7B0\x2d0B8F.service
           696ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-55.mount
           690ms plymouth-read-write.service
           651ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
           643ms rtkit-daemon.service
           642ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
           629ms resolvconf.service
           579ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-91.mount
           551ms snap-core18-941.mount
           519ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           517ms pppd-dns.service
           504ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           500ms systemd-resolved.service

           488ms plymouth-start.service
           457ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
           428ms console-setup.service
           399ms dns-clean.service
           392ms boot-efi.mount
           319ms alsa-restore.service
           314ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
           272ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-818.mount
           269ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
           267ms snap-core18-782.mount
           233ms systemd-random-seed.service
           232ms setvtrgb.service
           228ms kerneloops.service
           224ms hddtemp.service
           204ms snapd.seeded.service
           202ms blk-availability.service
           188ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e2648b12\x2df71d\x2d461a\x2dac
           179ms ufw.service
           155ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           153ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           114ms dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.swap
           112ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
            92ms user@1000.service
            54ms snapd.socket
            41ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
            20ms ureadahead-stop.service
             8ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             6ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             3ms systemd-modules-load.service
```

sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @56.382s
└─multi-user.target @56.382s
  └─hddtemp.service @56.353s +28ms
    └─network-online.target @56.339s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @48.111s +8.227s
        └─NetworkManager.service @41.370s +6.692s
          └─dbus.service @40.624s
            └─basic.target @40.316s
              └─sockets.target @40.316s
                └─snapd.socket @40.313s +2ms
                  └─sysinit.target @40.268s
                    └─apparmor.service @39.016s +1.251s
                      └─local-fs.target @39.015s
                        └─run-snapd-ns-canonical\x2dlivepatch.mnt.mount @51.091s
                          └─run-snapd-ns.mount @49.006s
                            └─swap.target @39.435s
                              └─dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.swap @39.009s +425ms
                                └─dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.device @39.008s
~
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TeamViewer is taking up a lot of your boot time. I'd suggest disabling its ability to start at boot or outright using `sudo apt remove` on it. Snaps slow down system performance a lot, if you do not use snaps I would suggest removing it (though this is dangerous if you run GNOME, I only advocate it if you run xfce, lde or kde)

EDIT: I've talked with a few tech friends of mine, you seem to have A LOT of snaps. Start getting in the habit of installing .deb files or using `apt` instead of snap all the time. Snap volumes are loaded in dev-loop files, which you have a lot of that take up a lot of time. Try removing some snaps and using the repos or .deb instead

Comment: just now i have removed team viewer but still more time to boot

Comment: Can you edit your post with the new information?

Comment: I've edited my post, Jaydeep.